# Why does my compiler not recognise a typedef in another included header file?

Tags: c, header, include

I have a problem where the compiler (linker?) does not seem to detect a typedef in another included header file. I have two header files:

```
// ConstantsVariables.h

#ifndef CONSTANTSVARIABLES_H
#define CONSTANTSVARIABLES_H
#include "CellList.h"

extern double boxLength_x, boxLength_y;

typedef struct Position {
    double x;
    double y;
} Position;

typedef struct Particle {
    Position position;
    int inWhichCell;
    double localOrientation;
    double initialAngle;
    double rotatedAngle;
    int insideGrain;
} Particle;

#endif /* CONSTANTSVARIABLES_H */
```

and

```
// CellList.h

#ifndef CELLLIST_H
#define CELLLIST_H
#include "ConstantsVariables.h"

typedef struct Cell {
    int numParticles;
    Particle **particles;
} Cell; 

typedef struct CellList {
    int numCols, numRows, numCells;
    double cellLength_x, cellLength_y;
    Cell *cells;
} CellList;

CellList *createCellList(void);
void destroyCellList(CellList *cellList);

#endif /* CELLLIST_H */
```

with matching `.c` files that implement the CellList functions and definitions for `boxLength_x/y`. However, when I try to compile my main file, which has these headers included and uses the variables/functions in them, I get an error in `CellList.h` saying `unknown type name 'Particle'`. What am I missing?

Comment: carefully follow your defines and includes which will show why circular includes are not good.

Comment: @stark I thought because I'm using include guards this is not a problem? Is this not true?

Comment: it is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConstantsVariables.h` includes `CellList.h` before it has `typedef … Particle;`. `CellList.h` uses `Particle`, so `Particle` is not defined where `CellList.h` uses it.

Although `CellList.h` has `#include "ConstantsVariables.h"`, at that point `ConstantsVariables.h` has already defined `CONSTANTSVARIABLES_H`, so the `#ifndef CONSTANTSVARIABLES_H` in `ConstantsVariables.h` causes the rest of the contents of `ConstantsVariables.h` not to be processed.

You should design your source and header files to form a tree structure: Each file should include only files “lower” in the tree. (In computer science, tree structures are generally drawn with the root node at the top and leaves toward the bottom.) There should be no loops in the includes.

Nothing in `ConstantsVariables.h` depends on anything in `CellList.h`, so there is no need for `ConstantsVariables.h` to `#include "CellList.h"` at its beginning. It could be removed.

If you intended `ConstantsVariables.h` to be some general header file for your project that can be included so that every source file can include it and not pick out individual headers to include, then it should be the file that depends on other headers and other headers should not depend on it. That means `CellList.h` should not have `#include "ConstantsVariables.h"`. Instead, move the declarations in `ConstantsVariables.h` to another file, such as one named `PositionParticle.h`. Inside `ConstantsVariables.h`, replace the moved declarations with `#include PositionParticle.h`. In `CellList.h`, change `#include "ConstantsVariables.h"` to `#include "PositionParticles.h"`.